# Is it possible to index the hashamaps, in an Arraylist?

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist

Is it possible to index hashmaps , in an arraylist.

```
List<Map<String,String>> list_str=new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
Map<String,String> map_str=new HashMap<String,String>();

map_str.put("Name", "rrrrr");
map_str.put("Age", "23");
list_str.add(map_str);
System.out.println(list_str);

map_str.put("Name", "aaaa");
map_str.put("Age", "32");
list_str.add(map_str);
System.out.println(list_str);
```

For the above mentioned code,I get the output as

```
[{Age=32,Name=aaaa},{Age=32,Name=aaaa}].
```

But , I would like to have the output as

```
[{Age=23,Name=rrrr},{Age=32,Name=aaaa}].
```

Comment: What do you mean by index the map ?

Comment: What you want is a list of pairs?

Comment: You are adding a reference to the same Map into the ArrayList, twice. If you want to index 2 different HashMaps, you will need to create seperate Objects.

Comment: In HashMap the key must unique otherwise the value will be replace by the last value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behavior.

When you added an object in any of collection type, than the collection just holds the reference of that object. It won't create new object and holed that.

So in your case, You have created an object of `HashMap` and using the same object again. That's why the data is getting override.

Probably the code should be like:

```
List<Map<String,String>> list_str=new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
Map<String,String> map_str=new HashMap<String,String>();

map_str.put("Name", "rrrrr");
map_str.put("Age", "23");
list_str.add(map_str);
System.out.println(list_str);

map_str = new HashMap<String,String>();

map_str.put("Name", "aaaa");
map_str.put("Age", "32");
list_str.add(map_str);
System.out.println(list_str);
```

Comment: If this solved your issue, please accept the answer. Later this will help others :)

Answer (score 0):

You are putting all your entries into the same map and adding it to the list twice. You need to create a new HashMap for each entry:

```
List<Map<String,String>> list_str = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

Map<String,String> map_str_1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
map_str_1.put("Name", "rrrrr");
map_str_1.put("Age", "23");
list_str.add(map_str_1);

Map<String,String> map_str_2 = new HashMap<String,String>();    
map_str_2.put("Name", "aaaa");
map_str_2.put("Age", "32");
list_str.add(map_str_2);

System.out.println(list_str);
```